# Using contracts to deploy game logic

Tags: contract-design

I found a chess game on github that uses contracts to implement all of the game logic. Is this a wise idea?

https://github.com/ise-ethereum/on-chain-chess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all. I see that github project more like a way of learning and playing with smart contracts and ethereum than for making a real game. Actually is from the Technical University of Berlin.
The point is that you will pay for every transaction that you do, that is the gas and the cost of each execution. And if all your game is in blockchain that means that every move or every interaction will be one transaction. 
You can create your private blockchain cluster but even that will be computational expensive precisely to make the transactions secure. In a game you want to make it faster. 
If it would be a gambling game maybe I'll manage the cash transactions in ethereum, just as an idea.